# spark job fails due to timeout

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I am using spark-v2.4.5 with java1.8 in my spark job.
Its failing with below error

> Application application_1650878536374_11143 failed 1 times in previous
> 3600000 milliseconds (global limit =2; local limit is =1) due to
> ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1650878536374_11143_000001
> timed out. Failing the application

What does this mean (global limit =2; local limit is =1) ? how to fix this ?